# Difficult in grasping "the extent/limit of conformational space of a compound until it change its stereochemistry"

Tags: organic-chemistry, computational-chemistry, stereochemistry, theoretical-chemistry, conformers

I have heard that a conformational landscape encompasses all conformers that a compound has for *a specific stereoisomer*. I think it makes sense *verbally*, because if all conformers of a stereoisomer include all conformers for all stereoisomers and one (mistakenly) designates those all stereoisomer conformations to be conformers for a specific stereoisomer, it will require an interconversion (or change in permutational position) of one or multiple bonds to be broken to make a different stereoisomer.

While it seems to make *verbal* sense to me, my visual thinking is really against this. Searching on Google, "stereoisomer conformation" and "conformer" are always treated as two different realms having no connection in between.

I feel there should be an image (or someone has done a research article about this) showing a conformational landscape with a functional group bonded to a particular atom, showing differences in spatial 3D position. It suffices to show that "this coordinate position is still the same stereoisomer" but that if the functional group is extended, whether freely translated or rotated in drawing to somewhere, it will make a different stereoisomer and *it is convincing enough that its stereochemistry interconversion will have to break some bonds first.*

Any example would be fine, but I prefer the case of cis-trans conversion of a cyclohexane in its chair conformation with few functional groups, because my visualization is that *its functional group stereochemistry interconversion still does not need bond breaking (but why it would have a different stereoisomer though?).*

Thus, here is the general question. **What is the extent or limit of conformational space of a molecule (or specifically, a particular stereoisomer) that is spatially unique to it, but if further extended to all random positional permutations will change its stereochemistry so that it will have to break some bonds first to let that interconversion happen?**

Comment: How about being less verbose and maybe write something that is clear and specific?

Comment: Also it's a bad example. Butene is good, even blatant, one.

Comment: I want to know more about this though, this is important in stereochemistry education. +1 for you.

Comment: It would definitely help if you were more concise and provided the simplest example of the problem you are facing. Try to use more punctuation (shorter and clearer sentences). It appears that this is about nomenclature, and specifically the meaning of the word "conformation". If so, a brief answer would be that it depends on context.

Comment: @Mithoron What makes you think a butene is a better example than the author given even it is just a sitting planar that doesn't make any prominent conformational space.

Comment: @làntèrn Exactly because of that.

Comment: Watch your [terminology](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/103122/104336):
Conformers are also stereoisomers. What you probably mean is how to partition conformational space based on configurational isomerism.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/169059/is-there-a-formal-definition-of-identical-molecules

Comment: @BuckThorn I think the vote system is a bit *disgrace* to me as there are many questions have bad forms with short lines of "can you read my mind" and I am just telling my process of reading and infering a *bad* school textbook because as with the site's policy, I have to demonstrate how I can conclude to that question though.

Comment: @làntèrn Thank you for the vote anyway. The vote does enhance a reward for people who are curious and seems the site's policy doesn't adhere to this a bit.

Comment: @Mithoron I don't know why butene is a good example. You might want to flex your answer with stereochemistry of mathematical knots and braids, perhaps?

Comment: I just re-read the first paragraph and I think I understand the question a little better, maybe because of the edits. My first comment was not to give you a hard time or as an explanation of up or downvoting (by myself or anyone else). I just felt confused by what you had written. It could be because it is a difficult question, simply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea that conformational space can be partitioned by configurational isomers. The clearest cases are where you have to break bonds to end up with another configurational isomer, but that is actually not always the case. Atropisomerism also gives rise to different configurational isomers, even though they are just separated by a bond rotation with a very high barrier.

Your example with cyclohexane is actually a clear-cut case, since you really need to break bonds to switch from *cis* to *trans*. I visualized all possible chair conformations and the partitioning into configurational subspaces. There are [more conformers](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/32970/conformations-of-cyclohexane) that I left out for simplification.

[image: Conformational space partitioning for cyclohexane-1,2-d2]

If you still don't see why you need bond breaking, I recommend playing around with a molecular model kit.

In summary, the partitioning of conformers into distinct configurational isomers happens when they are interconverted by a process with a high barrier (*i.e.* bond breaking, hindered rotations, polytopal rearrangements, *etc.*).

Comment: I will edit the comment a bit while writing.

Comment: I get it now. Thank you very much for clearing up and sharing this. Seems like I got the wrong terminology classification then (as you noted in the question's comment). Let me conclude this. So, a molecule has a global stereoisomer space (*not a global conformational space*) that can be partitioned into whether the interconversion of this space permutation will make a different configuration (configurational space, *not stereochemical space*) or not (conformational space).

Comment: The configurational space can be generated by some processes that the bond breaking process is not always a sole requirement to make a different configuration because it can be interconverted by another process requiring high barrier *i.e.* a hindered rotation to make atropisomers. I believe enzymatic catalysis performs this more commonly than the frequency it mentioned in the textbooks though.

Comment: Thank you very much for sharing this. The chair conformations in each configurational subspaces of cis and trans configurations are aesthetically pleasing to me as I can imagine with the given equlibrium arrows. I will affirm it later with my slo-mo molecular dynamics simulation to see each process. Again, thank you very much.

Comment: By the way, where do you obtain the picture? The link you gave is quite a bit different source one

Comment: @Leticia I drew it myself while focusing on double Newman projection. Btw. the intermediate conformers you can expect during a ring flip process are well known: [link](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/45197/104336).

Comment: Fun fact: In theory you could also argue that the two configurations are separated by a polytopal rearrangement with a very high barrier instead of bond breaking. Such processes are in fact known for certain amines.

Comment: Ah I see, the diagram looks improved and surely it looks like a diagram that is ready to be published in a journal. Thank you for the detailed diagram anyway.

Comment: It seems like the research progress in this field is blooming very well. From the link you have given to me, I found a lot of new concepts from there. Ring puckering of various heterocycles and macrocycles, pyramidal inversion, polytopal rearrangement like a Rubik cube, molecular machine, and so on. Seems like I have already jumped into a rabbit hole deeper.

Comment: Welcome to the world of applied computational chemistry ;)